# How to load img and pdf when javascript function $.get() is called?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I'm coding a website with nodejs for personal purpose. For this, i load one main page with a responsive content in right container (links on left) filled with html string that I load with ajax request to a MongoDb database. There is png and pdf files I need to load in several content but they did get reach (files not showing).

...html saved as String in MongoDb

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/views/src/cv.pdf" id="cv"></iframe>
<img src="http://localhost:3000/public/images/php.png">
```

...javascript

```
//Ajax request
function chargerPage(page){
    // console.log(page);
    $.get({
        url: '/portfolio',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {nom: page}
    }).done(function(page){
        // console.log(page.content[0]);
        var right_content = document.getElementById('right_content');
        var json = page.content[0];
        // console.log(json);
// json['content'] is a string
        right_content.innerHTML = json['content'];
    })
}
```

...

Well, I'd like my pictures and pdf show up when I load the content asked by user.
Thank for helping, I'm here to give more informations if needed!

Cordially, Skunka.

Comment: What is your question here? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is why my pdf and img files aren't loaded in my content when I use .innerHTML method in ajax .done() with my string 'json['content']? I have 404 error instead.

Comment: So add you this question as is in your question. :) It will be much clear for someone else that want to help you. 

With this, an 404 error mean that you can't access your file. Can you access them with the link you provide?

Comment: I searched a lot and i found what was wrong, as img src i put the whole link instead of juste the img file name because my server were looking into the public folder. It wasn't a $.get() problem. Problem is solve!